# Table disappears completely in Firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, html-table

This is my first post and I have been away from both HTML and CSS for quite a while, so please forgive me if this is an obvious question or if my code is messy or inconsistent. I had to look up different solutions for parts of this log in page I am working on.

My problem is that while this page works fine in both Chrome and Opera, in Firefox and Internet Explorer everything before the link and button disappears and they get stuck on top of the page.

Could you help me out with why this might be?

The special characters are needed because this will be in Swedish.

HTML:

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="logindiv">
      <img src="AAA.png" style="width: 80px; height: 80px;"/>
      <img src="BBB.jpg" style="width: 80px; height: 80px;"/>

      <h1>V&auml;lkommen</h1>
      <br/><br/><br/><br/>

      <div id="logindiv">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="user.png"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="anv&auml;ndarnamn" name="username" id="user" style="color: #BCC8CC; text-align: center; font-family: 'jaapokki-regular', Helvetica, sans-serif;"
              onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'anv&auml;ndarnamn';} this.style.color='#BCC8CC';"
              onfocus="if (this.value == 'anv&auml;ndarnamn') {this.value = '';} this.style.color='#606060';" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="password.png"></td>
            <td><input type="password" value="l&ouml;senord" name="pwd" id="pwd" style="color: #BCC8CC; text-align: center; font-family: 'jaapokki-regular', Helvetica, sans-serif;"
              onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'l&ouml;senord';} this.style.color='#BCC8CC';"
              onfocus="if (this.value == 'l&ouml;senord') {this.value = '';} this.style.color='#606060';" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <p><a href="password.html">Har du gl&ouml;mt ditt l&ouml;senord?</a></p>

        <table>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td id="login"><a href="cases.html"><input type="button" name="btn" class="btn-style" value="LOGGA IN"/></a></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <p></p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'jaapokki-regular';
    src: url('jaapokki-regular.eot');
    src: url('jaapokki-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('jaapokki-regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('jaapokki-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('jaapokki-regular.svg#jaapokki-regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

a {
  color: #6e8196;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
    background-color: #FFFEF5;
    color: #606060;
    font-family: "jaapokki-regular", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "jaapokki-regular", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #606060;
}

div#logindiv {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 220px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "jaapokki-regular", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

td {
   height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

td#login {
   height: 80px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.user-style{
  color: #606060;
}
.btn-style{
    border : solid 1px #606060;
    font-size : 17px;
    color : #fffef5;
    padding : 4px 12px;
    background-color : #6e8196;
  font-family: "jaapokki-regular", Helvetica, sans-serif;

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand the purpose of position:relative in terms of what i think you want it to do....  If you're looking to center things, try using `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: I guess you can check the browser compability of css transform.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: You are right, @briansol; I do not understand that many things about it, because as I said I'm only getting back to scripting after a long, long absence. Thank you for your suggestion, I will check it out.

Comment: Update: "margin" seems to work perfectly for the table, but not for "div".

Comment: You ought to stop using tables for layout. Tables are for... tables. Lists of information. Any layout/presentation structure should be accomplished using appropriate semantic tags and css. You mentioned that you've been away from HTML for a while -- using tables for layout structure is a dead idea.

Comment: Also, those inline styles.... move 'em to CSS classes :p

Comment: @Chris, it seems like I have to use tables because they're a convenient way to organize and center a grid that is compatible with all the browsers. Do you have an alternative? Trying to use div with transform was awful for anything other than Chrome and Opera.

You're absolutely right about the inline styles. I will be cleaning the code up after I figure out how to set things up.

Comment: @HermesJ.Pappas Yeah... you've been away for a while :p There are lots of ways to have a centered grid, a fluid grid, 100% cross-browser. These problems have been solved, and well. HTML5 and CSS3 has answers for any reason one would have used a table for layout in the past. Here's a plucked-from-Google list of ["responsive grid"](http://mashable.com/2013/04/26/css-boilerplates-frameworks/), I personally recommend Foundation. Tables are done. Also, you don't need to use transform. Being attached to it creates an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: @Chris, thanks for the link. One question, though: do older versions of browsers support HTML5 and CSS3? The solution I will be working on may be used in archaic IT settings (these are medical professionals, they don't have much technical knowledge and their IT departments tend to be resistant to updates) so my solution needs to be as bare-bones as possible.

Comment: Use http://caniuse.com/ to check feature support. If you have Google Analytics set up on the target site, you can feed the browser usage stats to caniuse to see how it impacts your actual user base. It doesn't sound like you'd have that demographic available in a medical institution intranet, but I would definitely find out how retro you have to get. Internet Explorer 6 and 7 could both be considered critical security risks. Even so, there are shims available to backfill almost all HTML5/CSS3 support for older browsers: http://modernizr.com/ -- a complete framework usually includes this

Comment: NB: I mentioned IE 6/7 because they are the only browsers that really have a compatibility concern. Most other browsers had vendor-prefixed versions (-moz-whatever, -webkit-whatever) of a lot of CSS3 available for a surprisingly long time, and since few HTML5 elements actually *do* anything, they've had defacto support too. A complete responsive CSS framework really covers your bases though, and has moderizr or the equivalent bundled in. It is more important to build for modern technology than continue to build bad products to support stuff that is going to die sooner rather than later.

Comment: Thank you once more, @Chris. I agree with you - I simply need to get a quick and dirty solution for now. My personal development comes later. Thanks once more for the help and information. Greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a rule that makes the whole table go out of the screen.

```
div#logindiv {
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Result without it:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'jaapokki-regular';
    src: url('jaapokki-regular.eot');
    src: url('jaapokki-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('jaapokki-regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('jaapokki-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('jaapokki-regular.svg#jaapokki-regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

a {
  color: #6e8196;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
    background-color: #FFFEF5;
    color: #606060;
    font-family: "jaapokki-regular", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "jaapokki-regular", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #606060;
}

div#logindiv {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  /* transform: translateY(-50%); */
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 220px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "jaapokki-regular", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

td {
   height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

td#login {
   height: 80px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.user-style{
  color: #606060;
}
.btn-style{
    border : solid 1px #606060;
    font-size : 17px;
    color : #fffef5;
    padding : 4px 12px;
    background-color : #6e8196;
  font-family: "jaapokki-regular", Helvetica, sans-serif;

}
```

```html
<div id="logindiv">
      <img src="AAA.png" style="width: 80px; height: 80px;"/>
      <img src="BBB.jpg" style="width: 80px; height: 80px;"/>

      <h1>V&auml;lkommen</h1>
      <br/><br/><br/><br/>

      <div id="logindiv">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="user.png"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="anv&auml;ndarnamn" name="username" id="user" style="color: #BCC8CC; text-align: center; font-family: 'jaapokki-regular', Helvetica, sans-serif;"
              onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'anv&auml;ndarnamn';} this.style.color='#BCC8CC';"
              onfocus="if (this.value == 'anv&auml;ndarnamn') {this.value = '';} this.style.color='#606060';" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="password.png"></td>
            <td><input type="password" value="l&ouml;senord" name="pwd" id="pwd" style="color: #BCC8CC; text-align: center; font-family: 'jaapokki-regular', Helvetica, sans-serif;"
              onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'l&ouml;senord';} this.style.color='#BCC8CC';"
              onfocus="if (this.value == 'l&ouml;senord') {this.value = '';} this.style.color='#606060';" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <p><a href="password.html">Har du gl&ouml;mt ditt l&ouml;senord?</a></p>

        <table>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td id="login"><a href="cases.html"><input type="button" name="btn" class="btn-style" value="LOGGA IN"/></a></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <p></p>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @emmanuel. That code was something I found as an easy way to center something vertically. Commenting it did, indeed, bring back the elements, but their vertical alignment is all out of whack. I guess I can look into it a bit more and come back or maybe ask a different question for that problem. Not sure what the protocol is here for that.

Comment: Nice to hear that! If you want to vertical align middle the whole div you could use `vertical-align` property.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that doing away with transform altogether was better. Instead of it, I used these little bits to center my div and table:

```
div {
  position:absolute;
  top:25%;
  left:25%;
  right:25%;
}

table#login {
  width: 220px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "jaapokki-regular", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Thanks to everyone for their help.